# Criteria and GPS in SDK 5.0 and later

Tags: blackberry

I'm currently developing a BB application and I need to get my current position.

In BB models with v5.0 it's ok, but in BB with v6.0 I always get the locationProvider as null. (The gps is turned on).

Anyone has an idea that what could happen and how to solve it?

The piece of code that I use is:

```
private boolean startLocationUpdate() {
    boolean retval = false;

    try {
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);

        criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);

        locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);

        if (locationProvider == null) {

            Runnable showGpsUnsupportedDialog = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    Dialog.alert("GPS is not supported on this platform...");
                    // System.exit( 1 );
                }
            };

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(
                    showGpsUnsupportedDialog); // Ask event-dispatcher
                                                // thread to display dialog
                                                // ASAP.
        } else {

            locationProvider.setLocationListener(
                    new LocationListenerImpl(), interval, 1, 1);

            retval = true;
        }
    } catch (LocationException le) {
        System.err
                .println("Failed to instantiate the LocationProvider object, exiting...");
        System.err.println(le);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the API documentation for [Criteria](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/location/Criteria.html), you are requesting Cellsite mode. The documentation for [LocationProvider.getInstance()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/location/LocationProvider.html#getInstance%28javax.microedition.location.Criteria%29) specifies:

```
a LocationProvider meeting the defined criteria or null if a LocationProvider that meets the defined criteria can't be returned but there are other supported available or temporarily unavailable providers that do not meet the criteria.
```

So the API is telling you that Cellsite is not supported, but there are other supported modes available. If you want to use the GPS you need to specify a Criteria that calls for Autonomous mode.

Comment: I tried different providers and the result is the same :S. It's really strange, only in BB Torch don't work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I've been working on 7.0 and 7.1 for a while. I don't recall any issues with 6.0. I normall use a null Criteria.